# setState in didComponentMount sets state property to undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm running this react app and getting the error :-
'TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined'

In this, constructor is being called twice and this.state.cats is equal to [] that time,
then didComponentMount is being called twice and setState({cats:catsList}) sets this.state.cats = undefined for some reason.
Noob here, any help is appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CatsList from './CatsList';
import logo from './logo.png';
import SearchBox from './SearchBox';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            cats: [],
            searchField:''
        }
    }

    onCatNameSearch = (event) => {
        this.setState({searchField : event.target.value})
    }

    render(){
        const filterdCats = this.state.cats.filter(cat => cat.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchField.toLowerCase()));
        return (
            <div className="tc">
                <img src={logo} className="w-20" alt="logo" />
                <SearchBox searchChange={this.onCatNameSearch}/>
                <CatsList cats={filterdCats} />
            </div>);
    }

    //since it is part of react, no need for arrow functions
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('https://mak947.github.io/kitties/cats.json')
        .then(response =>{
            response.json();
        })
        .then(catsList =>{
            this.setState({cats: catsList});
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the promise chaining wrong, if you want to add another `.then`, you need to return the value, so you need to return `response.json()`

```
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('https://mak947.github.io/kitties/cats.json')
        .then(response =>{
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(catsList =>{
            this.setState({cats: catsList});
        })
    }
```

Comment: couldn't have sighted that on my own XD thanks a lot ^_^